# Self signed cert validation using X509TrustManager:checkServerTrusted

Tags: java, android, security

X509TrustManager:checkServerTrusted , i use this api for validating certs obtained , the first time it throws an exception for a self signed cert. User is displayed with warning dialogue for that website. if the user continues and website is displayed.

Now i refresh that page again , and the same cert is validated using the same api , but here i do not see any exception , is the trust manager updated with this cert value? is this suppose to be the expected behavior

All this is being done in android environment

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using a WebView. In such a case the SSL connections are handled in a different way. If you want to implement a custom behavior for accepting self-signed SSl certificates you have to implement the interface [android.webkit.SslErrorHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/SslErrorHandler.html) and set it as SSLErrorHandler in your WebView class.